# Need help : How to solve this integral equation?

Tags: integration, integral-equations

There's an integral equation that I can't solve :

$$y(x) = x + \int_0^x \left(\frac{t}{x}-tx\right)y(t)\,dt+\int_x^1 \left(\frac{x}{t}-tx\right)y(t)\,dt$$

I tried differentiating it three times, but it gave me a third order differential equation that I couldn't solve.

Does anyone have a way to solve this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes. Take the first derivative by Liebniz rule. Notice you will get terms which are like $\frac{1}{x}y$. I.e. an ODE of the form $y' = \frac{1}{x}y - 2\int_0^x \frac{1}{x^2}y dt$. Now multiply by $x^2$ and differentiate to get a linear 2nd order ODE.

Comment: Thank you. I did exactly as you said, but I still get integrals in the ODE.

Comment: Can you show me

Comment: If you differentiate three times, and then reduce the order, I get $$x^2y^{''}+xy^{'}+(2x-1)y=C$$, where C is a constant

Comment: Your last $y$ is probably a linear combination of some products of Bessel functions.

Comment: I got: $x^2 y'' + y - xy' = 0$

Comment: @fGDu94; If it is $x^2 y'' + y - xy' = C$, the problem is quite simple.